# Linq Joined Query Group by Projection into Master Detail

Tags: c#, linq

Need help for projecting this query output into a master detail object graph.

The query also needs to be grouped by Master fields.

The expected result is every master object will have collection of detail object.

```
var q = from ee in db.Pages
        from ff in db.SubModules.Where(p => p.submoduleid == ee.submoduleid)
        from gg in db.Modules.Where(p => p.moduleid == ff.moduleid) 
        select new 
                            {
                           // detail fields
                                pageid = ee.pageid,
                                pagename = ee.pagename,
                                pageurl = ee.pageurl,
                                pgorder = ee.orderno,
                                pgstat = ee.status,

                           //Master fields from here
                                smid = ff.submoduleid,
                                smnm = ff.submodulename,
                                smorder = ff.orderno,
                                moduleid = gg.moduleid,
                                modulename = gg.modulename
                            };
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The actual scenario involves 11 tables and is very complex. I need something that does not break the existing query join structure.

**EDIT 2**

Master DTO should have smid, smnm, smorder, moduleid, modulename and a collection of detail DTOs which will have the rest of the fields.

Comment: Did you by any chance flip Modules and SubModules? I have a hard time imagining SubModules owning Modules.

Comment: @GertArnold Modules has SubModules which have pages. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the query and you can create a new query using the ToLookup extension, from the current projection (q).
Use the Master data as the lookup key.

```
var md = q.ToLookup(ee=> new 
                    {
                        pageid = ee.pageid,
                        pagename = ee.pagename,
                        pageurl = ee.pageurl,
                        pgorder = ee.orderno,
                        pgstat = ee.status,
                    })
              .Select(c=> new 
                {
                    Master = c.Key, 
                    Details = c.Select(ff=>new 
                        {
                            smid = ff.submoduleid,
                            smnm = ff.submodulename,
                            smorder = ff.orderno,
                            moduleid = ff.moduleid,
                            modulename = ff.modulename  
                        }).ToList()
                });
```